# MongoDB Search, Skip Special Characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose a field(version) contains value `1.12.34` or `10.2.3.5` or any string which contains `.` at any position. So is there is any way to get the document by searching for `11234` or `10235`, basically without `.` in the string.

Comment: You must save the field as you want to search it with. There are some aggregation tricks that can do the trick for you but that are not efficient in terms of performance here.

Comment: then, I need to create one more field like `versionStr` which will contain the value without `.`, is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to solve this problem

```js
var str = '1.12.34'
var newString = str.replace(/[^0-9]+/ig, "");
console.log(newString)
```

Here is an example. 
So you can use your version field with replace function using the regex, don't need another field to store version value without dot(.)